# How do make broadcom proprietary driver for BCM4312 [14e4:4315] to work with channels 12-13 in Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, broadcom

For my Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c], the open source driver makes DL rate stuck to 2Mb/s (~240kB/s) when UL reaches 8/10 Mb/s, any channel. The broadcom driver reaches these 8/10Mb/s both for UL & DL for channel 1-11, but unfortunately I can't connect to channels 12-13 APs. I enabled proposed repos so that I can get the latest linux-firmware-nonfree 1.14ubuntu3 and can enable latest bcmwl-kernel-source  6.30.223.271+bdco, with no success. The opensource driver seems to be called `b43-pci-bridge`, when the proprietary seems to be called `wl`.

```
iw reg get
country 00:
(2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
(2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
(2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
(5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
(5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
```

Comment: Are those channels even legal where you are located?

Comment: Please edit your question to show: `iw reg get`

Comment: Done, above is my `iw reg get`. @ubfan1 ,  this depends on where I am located. I'm often in places that use channels 12-13, seldom channel 14. Do you mean computers running Ubuntu are regional locked-out? Or wifi cards or drivers?

Comment: Set your current country code into file /etc/default/crda, and the legal channels should be made available next time wireless is enabled.   Apparently, you have no country code now, so you get a default.

Comment: I tried all combination of edit `/etc/default/crda` to `REGDOMAIN=EU` or `REGDOMAIN=FR` (reboot required) and `sudo iw reg set EU` or `sudo iw reg set FR` without success. `sudo iwlist scan` will only shows some cells in channels range 1-11 (private neighbours).

Comment: Can I add here a sample of `dmesg` and `iw list` outputs?